# creating Spring boot starter project

Tags: spring-boot

When i create my spring Boot starter project im getting error as maven configuration problem. Please help me to solve.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FyEh1.png)

Comment: Do you have maven installed? Problem seems to be from pom.xml and I see the error it says Maven configuration. Double check those.

Answer (score 1):

Similar Bug was reported in eclipse: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=547340

You can fix this by temporary downgrading the maven jar plugin version to 3.1.1 from 3.1.2. Add this to the properties section:

```
<maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-jar-plugin.version>
```

In your pom.xml

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-jar-plugin.version>
</properties>
```

**Update:** A fix has been released. Click Help > Check for updates in Eclipse/STS and install the newest m2e connector.