# Error in POM.xml while creating spring starter in STS

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, pom.xml

[image]
Error in pom.xml while creating spring starter application in STS

No error message show

Comment: What do you think the **errors** tab is for. Or hovering over the red icon. This will give you information about wha tis wrong.

Comment: This is the latest eclipse surprise bug , see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56455851/maven-pom-xml-problem-unknown-error-at-top-line-xml-version-1-0-encoding/56456035#56456035)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [creating Spring boot starter project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56351172/creating-spring-boot-starter-project)

Answer (score -2):

You are using the `<relativePath>` tag, however you are just closing it on declaration and it is not meant to work in that way.
If you want to use it you have to add it like

```
<relativePath>path/to/element</relativePath>
```

Comment: `<relativePath />` is perfectly valid.

Comment: As mentioned by @M.Deinum, using `<relativePath />` is fine, and is mentioned in [the documentation](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0.3/maven-model/maven.html#class_parent). Relevant part: *"Set the value to an empty string in case you want to disable the feature and always resolve the parent POM from the repositories."*